# Perl file size limit

Tags: perl, file, command-line-interface

I know how to read|write|open files in perl. What am trying to achieve is this; how do I create a new file when the existing file exceeds 'x' size. For instance, I have a 3MB file size, before writing to the same file, check the size, if size exceed 3MB, create a new one, chmod it if needed, then write.

I don't know if my question is clear -

Answer (score 6):

`$size = -s '/path/to/file.txt';`

if(($size / 1048576) > 3) { 
  print "too big";
}
else {
  do_something();
}

Answer (score 2):

You can use stat for this:

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html

stat gives you a lot of information about a given file, including the size.

Example:

```
use File::stat; 
my $filesize = stat("test.txt")->size;
```

Comment: am reading up on that quickly. I will post my solution here ASAP. I get the logic though :)

Answer (score 2):

Once you've determined that the file is big enough to rotate using [`-s`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html), [Logfile::Rotate](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Logfile%3a%3aRotate) can be used to do the rotation.